# async callback not calling properly

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
triviaCtrl.answer = function(req, res) {
  //console.log(req.query.name);
  var data = {};
  var pointdata = {};
  var datas = {
    "Status": 0,
    "Message": ""
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var newAnswer = function(cb) {
      data.questionId = req.query.questionId;
      data.userId = req.query.userId;
      data.correctAnswer = req.query.correctAnswer;
      data.userAnswer = req.query.userAnswer;
      data.type = req.query.type;
      data.point = req.query.point;
      Answer.create(data, cb);
    }
    var checkuserpoint = function(cb) {
      Point.findOne({
        userId: req.query.userId
      }, function(err, result, cb) {
        if (result) {
          result.availablePoint = Number(result.availablePoint) + Number(req.query.point);
          result.totalWinPoint = Number(result.totalWinPoint) + Number(req.query.point);
          result.save(cb);
        } else {
          pointdata.userId = req.query.userId;
          pointdata.totalWinPoint = req.query.point;
          pointdata.redeemPoint = 0;
          pointdata.availablePoint = req.query.point;
          Point.create(pointdata, cb);
        }
      });
    }

    async.waterfall([newAnswer, checkuserpoint], function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        //reject(err);
        datas["Status"] = 0;
        datas["Message"] = err;
        res.json(datas);
      } else {
        datas["Status"] = 1;
        datas["Message"] = result;
        res.json(datas);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

if I remove  "newAnswer,checkuserpoint"  one function from there it is working but when I'm using both together then it not give any response . but function working properly

Comment: I don't see you ever `resolve` nor `reject` the Promise you return.

Answer (score 0):

Second and further functions in `async.waterfall` take arguments passed to previous fucntion's callback

See `arg1`, `arg2` in 2nd function.

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

Comment: thats why i'm not getting any response when i use both function together ?

Comment: cb(null , req);   in newAnswer and in   checkuserpoint.  
if(result)
                    { 
                      result.save(cb);
                      cb(null , result);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       cb(null , pointdata);
                    }

now its return the  new error  "  TypeError: cb is not a function. "